# attachEvent is not a function - Using Module Pattern

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to build a JavaScript module to better understand the pattern.  I am trying to attach click events to a button with addEventListener and attachEvent but I can not get my console.log to register.

I am also getting an error that says "TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function"

Here is a fiddle that I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/rL5xp/

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>The color is <span class="js-print">green</span>.</p>
<button class="js-button">Click Here</button>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var settings = [
    {color : 'green'},
    {color : 'blue'},
    {color : 'red'}
];

var $ele = {  
     span   : $('.js-print'),
     button : $('.js-button')
};

var ChangeColor = (function(s, $element) {

  var init = function() {
    bindBrowserActions();   
  }

  var bindBrowserActions = function() {        
    addClick($element.button, 'click', function() {
         console.log('click');   
    });        
  }

  var addClick = function(element, evnt, funct) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
    }
    //addEventListener is not supported in <= IE8
    else {
        return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
    } 
  }

  return {
    init : init
  }

})(settings, $ele);

(function() {
  ChangeColor.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `addClick` method the argument `element` was passed as a jQuery wrapper element, not a dom element reference so it does not have methods like `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`.

Since `element` is a jQuery wrapper element you can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) to register the event handlers.

```
var addClick = function(element, evnt, funct) {
    element.on(evnt,  funct)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z7BWj/)

Comment: Thank you!  This had worked in the past when I used ID's on the elements and document.getElementById.  Thank you for the great explanation.